# Can we deactivate a pulished apk

Tags: android, apk, bundle

Uploaded a bundle on playstore and now I wish to deactivate it. As I have uploaded a new bundle for the users but users cannot see it. Any chance I can deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

there's no need to deactivate anything - releases are just not instantly available, unless using the "timed publishing approach", where one can set the exact time when it should become available; otherwise it ordinary takes 2-4 hours until it will be available - there is no default time-frame. I'd only contact the Play Store support, in case nothing changed within 24 hours.

Comment: how can we do this?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria how to do what? just wait for it... there's nothing you can do, assuming you've already published it, but it doesn't show up. this doesn't happen instantly.

Comment: I dont want users to install the old build, still only the old build is visible to users

Comment: @ParthAnjaria that's unfortunate and I understand your concern - still, it takes time... and the time it takes most likely depends on how many releases are being made overall, which makes it impossible to estimate or guarantee any specific time-frame.

Comment: If you have uploaded a new version of the bundle, then you're all set: all users will only receive the new one.

Comment: @Pierre the the problem is that they won't receive it instantly, because the release procedure is a tad asynchronous... it's kind of a pipeline, which seems to have it's limits. also the pre-release tests often take quite a while to show results.